# Simplifying the blogger template (stripping macros and possibly more)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, macros, blogger

Our website is hosted on blogger and is beta.planthro.org

Template code is available at
https://github.com/planthro/biblio
file name: plantho_biblio_main_template.xml

All that we need are:

- Header (same for posts and pages),
- body (different for posts and pages),
- right-sliding-sidebar (same for posts and pages),
- left-sliding-sidebar (similar to the right-sidebar; currently not implemented)
- footer (same for posts and pages; footer link should open modal windows of the size of the body).

Aim is to keep a responsive template, that enforces landscape view and is optimized for 100% zoom on all landscape screen sizes.

How can I get rid of macros (macro:include) in the blogger template. If I do so, I can't make the template work.

We are looking to simplify the current template. Its 2650 lines long and has a myriad of divs and sections and specially the macros.

For example, in the last line of the code, even if I delete the completely unnecessary

```
<b:section-contents id='footer-2-1'/><b:section-contents id='footer-2-2'/>
```

I get a problem and this re-appears (macro at work I am sure, but why I don't know).

This may not be specific enough. All advice will go a long way helping us.

Answer (score 0):

There are three sections you need to remove:

- `<macro:includable id='some_section' var='some_var'>` ... `</macro:includable>`
- `<b:section-contents id='some_id'>` ... `</b:section-contents>`
- `<macro:include id='some_id' name='sections'>` ... `</macro:include>`

You need to remove **all three** of these macro sections in order for Blogger to allow you to  save your theme HTML.

Comment: Hello and thanks. I tried but ended up with xml error which I was not able to resolve.

My question would be, why can't even I remove 
<b:section-contents id='footer-2-1'/><b:section-contents id='footer-2-2'/>
from the last line?
Thanks much.

Comment: Dear Obsidian Age, thanks again. 
With the insight you gave, I have been able to free the footer from the macro, but the sidebars seem more tricky. 
In any case there's been a partial success and I have a starting point.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have been able to completely remove the macros now. It was a matter of doing it carefully. 
I had to modify <b:section-contents> to <b:section> and
remove a macro-generated section that picked a widget but instead manually include that widget in an existing section.

So overall the advice was good. Rather than simply removing the sections, I had to look inside them as to what was being 'dynamically' generated and instead generate it as static html/xml.

Thanks in deed.